# Django-Monitor - get_model() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to find a way to moderate items going into the database so that a super user must approve before things are displayed. I found that Django-monitor manages to do pretty much all of that, I have been reading and following the documentation ([here](http://django-monitor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html)) and whenever I call django_monitor.nq(model_name) I get an error saying:

```
get_model takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

I don't understand what is causing this problem and have been unable to find anything to help solve it.

Comment: are you sure that django-monitor is working with your django version? django-monitor was not updated for the last 3 years!

Comment: Please show us versions, and your model code please.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a lib problem. if you are certain that it is caused on that line, then the lib's work is getting the error. I doubt that it's a lib error, so a full traceback would help a lot, and the models declaration as well.
Also, see if your django version is supported by the lib.

By the way, that error is caused when you call a function with too many arguments.
imagine that you have a class

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, other):
        self.other=other
```

calling:

```
>>> Foo(1)
<Foo object at 0x7f27566f90d0>
>>> Foo(1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Foo(1) works because the class's **init** takes 2 arguments(self and other)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's incompatible with your django version. Looking at the [repo source](https://bitbucket.org/rajeesh/django-monitor/src/fc82464982b83da23727923d454b1bd3aef438a9/django_monitor/__init__.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#__init__.py-48) it seems like it was fixed:

```
    try:
        registered_model = get_model(
            model._meta.app_label, model._meta.object_name, False, False
        )
    except TypeError:
        # Django versions prior to 1.4 accept 3 params to get_model.
        registered_model = get_model(
            model._meta.app_label, model._meta.object_name, False
        )
```

Unless the error raised now is not a `TypeError`.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be because I'm using django 1.7, the point you mentioned is where it says the fault is but I cannot work out why it's failing. I may give django-moderation another go.

Comment: Ok this helps, for django 1.7, function's `get_model` 1 out of 3 expected parameters is `self`. So both the code in the `try` and `except` block have failed. https://github.com/django/django/blob/d92b08536d873c0966e8192e64d8e8bd9de79ebe/django/apps/registry.py#L186

Comment: So how would I fix that?

Comment: Well if you have to use this specific library, I would fork it, fix the code and submit a PR or reference my fork in the requirements.txt. One way to fix the code would be to remove the optional `False` arguments passed to `seed_cache=True, only_installed=True` and are no longer accepted by `get_model`, re-run the library tests and hope you didn't break anything!!

Answer (score 0):

`get_model()` was changed in 1.7 as explained in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.7/#introspecting-applications):

> The app registry has preserved some features of the old app cache.
>   Even though the app cache was a private API, obsolete methods and
>   arguments will be removed through a standard deprecation path, with
>   the exception of the following changes that take effect immediately:
>
> - [...]
> - The only_installed argument of get_model and get_models no longer exists, nor does the seed_cache argument of get_model.

Since django-monitor tries to pass at least one of these arguments to `get_model()`, it is incompatible with Django 1.7+. It only accepts the `app_label` and `model_name` arguments.